# Async return with delay - IllegalMonitorStateException

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, callable

I am trying to call method in new thread which will return something after delay using callable. It is falling due to **IllegalMonitorStateException**
Is it possible to encapsulate thread service that way, when I will just create instance of class, call method and that method will return object with delay?
Thank you in advance.

```
// ENTITY
public class Result {
    public String name;
    public int value;

    public Result(String name, int value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Result() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Result{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", value=" + value +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**Creation of thread with delay and return value**

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class AsyncCallable {

    public Result calculate() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        int delay = 5000;
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        Callable<Result> callable = () -> {
            this.wait(delay);
            return new Result("Name", 4);
        };

        Future<Result> future = executorService.submit(callable);
        executorService.shutdown();
        return future.get();
    }

}
```

**Calling method:**

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        AsyncCallable asyncCallable = new AsyncCallable();

        System.out.println(asyncCallable.calculate().toString());


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to stick to your case, any call to wait() must be enclosed in a synchronized block (see the method javadoc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait())). But, I think you should consider using built-in tools, like [Scheduled thread pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html). Using this, you can do the following :

```
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4);
// Execute a task after 5 seconds
scheduler.schedule(() -> new Result("Name", 4), 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Ok, so I've been down-voted, and apparently, my answer is not sufficient for the question author. Is it possible to get more details about what is wrong with my answer ? This way I could try to improve it.

Comment: Well I do not have enough rep for down-vote. Anyway I used your solution with ScheduledExecutorService and it works like a charm! I will vote after I'll get rep.
Thank you very much! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Because your `ExecutorService` only uses a single thread, it should be fine to just call `Thread#sleep` instead of `Object#wait`:

```
Callable<Result> callable = () -> {
    Thread.sleep(5_000);
    return new Result("Name", 4);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, this solution works, anyway it is not doing exactly what I expected. It should not pause whole application (but it is true that in my example it does not matter)